# form is not visible fully on mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, media-queries, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap4 (alpha) ,in my code the form is working properly and totally visible but on mobile devices when i want to type anything it breaks the alignment and the rest of the form part is not visible

```
#sectionOne{
  height:100vh;
  max-height:auto;
  background-color:#616161;
}
#sectionTwo{
  height:100vh;
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9p907s06/)

Comment: the issue is not occuring in your jsfiddle. unable to help

Comment: how can you get this issue in jsfiddle Just if you can try this in mobile you will

Comment: not happening on my mobile chrome

Comment: when you try to type then rest of the below parts are hiding behind the next div

Comment: is it possible to solve this by overflow concept??